# Detect space bar event on Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've searched the entire internet for something on this with no luck. I'm trying to detect if the user hits the space bar on a Mac app.

`-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent;` works great when the user presses on a character key, but not enter or space.

`-(BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent *)theEvent;` is called when the user hits the enter key or the arrow keys, but not the space bar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get it working by subclassing NSWindow and implementing this method:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString* keysPressed = [theEvent characters];
    if ( [keysPressed isEqualToString:@" "] )
    {
        if(theEvent.type==NSKeyDown)
            NSLog(@"spaceDown");
        if(theEvent.type==NSKeyUp)
            NSLog(@"spaceUp");
    }
}
```

Comment: Though this solution is causing a lot of other problems, so if anyone knows another way, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this other loop with the key number 32 according to the space bar constant.

```
    if ([theArrow length] == 1)
    {
        keyChar = [theArrow characterAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Dentro2 %hu", keyChar);
        switch (keyChar)
        {
            case 32: // Space Bar management

                break;              
        }
    }

    // Manage when any key is dropped.
    if(downOrUp == FALSE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Tecla soltada.");
        self.playerVelocity = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    }

// Methods to handle key push and key drop
    - (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
    {
        [self handleKeyEvent:event keyDown:YES];
    }

    - (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event
    {
        [self handleKeyEvent:event keyDown:NO];
    }
```

Comment: If you `#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>` then you can use `kVK_Space` rather than `32`.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon it by myself resently. Strangely enough, `keyDown:` event is detected only by the the method described by **moby**. But `keyUp:` works like a charm with space bar press

Answer (score 0):

After trying few solutions i come with one that din't break other things for me

```
@import Carbon;

typedef void (^CustomWindowSpacebarKeyCallback)(NSEventType eventType);

@interface CustomWindow : NSWindow

@property (nonatomic, copy) CustomWindowSpacebarKeyCallback spacebarKeyCallback;

@end

@implementation CustomWindow

- (void) sendEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   [super sendEvent:theEvent];

   if (([theEvent type] == NSKeyDown || [theEvent type] == NSKeyUp) && _spacebarKeyCallback) {
        NSString *keysPressed = [theEvent characters];
        if ([keysPressed length] == 1) {
            unichar keyChar = [keysPressed characterAtIndex:0];
            if (keyChar == kSpaceCharCode) {
                _spacebarKeyCallback([theEvent type]);
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```